# GET request parameters for a MessageField in AppEngine Endpoints is None

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

For some reason I am unable to read request parameters when using http_method=GET instead of POST.

```
@endpoints.method(RequestMessage,
                  ResponseMessage,
                  name='get',
                  path='mypath',
                  http_method='GET')
def get_challenge(self, request):
    # This is None in http_method=GET but works on POST
    print request.my_message_field
```

My message class is like this:

```
class MyMessage(messages.Message):
    id = messages.StringField(1)
    name = messages.StringField(2)

class RequestMessage(messages.Message):
    my_message_field = messages.MessageField(MyMessage, 1)
```

I am testing the API through the API Explorer. Any idea if I am doing something wrong or what?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters should be showing up as `my_message_field.id` and `my_message_field.name`.

The fundamental difference is that `GET` has no payload and `POST` does. As a result, your parameter namespace must be "flat" instead of nested JSON. So to accomodate this we flatten out the parameters as I mentioned above.

## UPDATE:

This must have been an issue with something not getting correctly ported to `devappserver`. I added a logger to `endpoints.apiserving` to determine what was passed from the API frontend to the App Engine backend:

**In production**:

```
'{"my_message_field":{"id":"x","name":"y"}}'
```

**In `devappserver2`**:

```
'{"my_message_field.name": ["y"], "my_message_field.id": ["x"]}'
```

When trying to parse via

```
from protorpc import remote
protocols = remote.Protocols.get_default()
json_protocol = protocols.lookup_by_content_type('application/json')
json_protocol.decode_message(RequestMessage, payload)
```

which is what the `api_server` does, this is what occurred

**In production**:

```
<RequestMessage
 my_message_field: <MyMessage
 id: u'x'
 name: u'y'>>
```

**In `devappserver2`**:

```
<RequestMessage>
```

Comment: Does that mean it's a bug in devappserver2? Should we file a bug somewhere? Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I've got it handled. I think it may be related to a feature/patch from the old `dev_appserver` that didn't get ported to `devappserver2` in time for a release.

Comment: @mkhatib I confirmed this has been correctly ported over to `devappserver2` and should be working in the next release. Sorry for the broken behavior. If it's really crucial it'll be working in `old_dev_appserver.py` for now :S

Comment: Thanks @bossylobster for the detailed replies. It's not crucial, I can work with POST for now.